# Компилятор меняет значение переменной при переполнении

Tags: c++

Программа выводит непонятный для меня ответ: -15478. В C++ новичок, хочу разобраться досконально в этом вопросе. Я использовал вместо int short, зная его ограничения. Но по приколу решил посмотреть. Почему выводится именно  такой ответ?

````
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    short num = 639882;
    cout << num;

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%5d%20%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5&searchOn=3) или [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%2b%2b%5d%20%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5&searchOn=3)

Comment: Несколько возможных объяснений. 1) Целое `639882` в двоичном виде равно `01001 11000011 10001010` (часть ведущих нулей опустим). Возьмём 16 младших битов этого числа (типичная размерность типа `short`): `11000011 10001010` — в [дополнительном коде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) это в точности равно `-15478`. 2) Будем из числа `639882` вычитать число `2^16 == 65536` до тех пор, пока не получим значение, представимое типом `short`. Результат равен `-15478`.

Comment: 3) Среди всех значений типа `short` возьмём такое, которое [сравнимо по модулю числа `2^16`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E) с числом `639882`. Это в точности `-15478`.

Comment: при переполнении возможностей типа C++ стандарт говорит, что дальнейшее поведение программы не определено и значение зависит от архитектуры, компилятора и настроек. Так как скорее всего у большинства программистов всё это общее с вами, то скорее всего один единичный бит попал на бит знака. И этот знак дал вам отрицательное значение.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Поведение программы не определено при переполнении при арифметических операциях.